# Granting app permission to bind to service

Tags: android, service

I have an app with multiple services. I have set permissions to access one of them.

```
<service
            android:name="com.example.MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="secret"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.Goal" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

How can I grant permission to another app (Client) to bind to this service? 
I tried adding `<uses-permission android:name="secret" />` to manifest of Client but it was unsuccessful. I can bind successfully if `android:permission` is not set in the service.

Comment: The `MyService` app will need to declare a `<permission android:name="..." />` element in its manifest – in the same area that you would have `<uses-permission>` elements – and it will need to be installed first, to make things simple.

Comment: @MikeM. I have multiple services defined, how to set permissions for one of them ? For the method suggested won't it set permissions for all of them ?

Comment: No, the `<permission>` element simply creates the permission. You still need the `android:permission` attribute on each `<service>` to guard that particular `Service`.

Comment: I have declared `<permission android:name="abc" />` and  `android:permission="secret"` in my Service manifest. In my Client manifest only setting `<uses-permission android:name="abc" />` should work?

Comment: `name` is the the actual permission, not some random string.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you please post a clear answer on how to make it work?

Comment: Is it worked on Android OS 12?